# SailsJS (waterline) model association

Tags: sails.js, waterline, model-associations

How can I define an association between 2 models, if the primary key in one model corresponds to 2 fields in the other one?
I have something like this:

```
Model1 {
 primaryKey
 field1,
 field2,
 field3
}

Model2 {
 primaryKey (is actually Model1.field1 + Model1.field2),
 fieldA,
 fieldB
}
```

I'd like to bring in the additional information from Model2 (fieldA, fieldB) into Model1. Any ideas on how to model this in Sails?